# JavaScript protyping - differences

Tags: javascript, prototyping

Here's my sample code

```js
function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype  = {
  constructor: Person,
  printInformation: function() {
    console.log(this.toString());
  },
  toString: function() {
    return "Name: " + this.name + ", Age: " + this.age;
  }
};

var person1 = new Person("Some Name", 15);
person1.printInformation();
console.log(typeof(person1));
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(person1) === Object.prototype);

var book = {
  title: "Some book",
  author: "Some author",
  printInformation: function() {
    console.log(this.toString());
  },
  toString: function() {
    return "Book: " + this.title + ", Author(s): " + this.author;
  }
};

book.printInformation();
var bookPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(book);
console.log(typeof(book));
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(book) === Object.prototype);
```

Output:

```
Name: Some Name, Age: 15
object
false
Book: Some book, Author(s): Some author
object
true
```

Why does `Object.getPrototypeOf(person1) === Object.prototype` return false while `Object.getPrototypeOf(book) === Object.prototype` return true?

Both are instances of object, both point to a prototype, I'd hope, both should return true. Kindly enlighten me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prototype chain of `person1` looks like this:

```
person1 ---> Person.prototype ---> Object.prototype ---> null
```

The prototype chain of `book` looks like this:

```
book ---> Object.prototype ---> null
```

The `Object.getPrototypeOf()` method returns the *next* item in the prototype chain. Therefore, `person1` does not return `Object.prototype` and is therefore `false`.

---

To get the `person1` to give `true`, you'd have to cycle calls until you reached `Object.prototype`.

```
var obj = person1

while (obj) {
    if (obj === Object.prototype) {
        console.log("found it!");
        break;
    }
    obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
}
```

---

Or if the prototype object is indeed on a function, you could just use `instanceof` instead.

```
person1 instanceof Object; // true
book instanceof Object; // true
```

The `instanceof` searches the prototype chain of the object you provide to see if it has any object that matches the `.prototype` of the function you provide, which in this case is the `Object` function.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. How about the second part. "Also, is there a preference amongst developers between creating classes using "function" or in JSON format? Advantage/Disadvantages, apart from readability?"

Comment: @KrishnanSriram: For implementing your own methods on an object, you should probably use a constructor function so that you're not extending `Object.prototype` unless you are fully aware of the ramifications. The other syntax isn't necessarily JSON syntax. It's object literal syntax and is useful for plain objects that need no enhancement, though constructor functions can be useful there too if there's a good bit of initialization to do.

Comment: @KrishnanSriram That is a primarily opinion-based question, and thus off-topic for Stack Overflow, so I removed that part from the main question. Also, just ask a single question at a time, not multiple ones.

Comment: @KrishnanSriram Advantages and disvantages is a broad subject. Best thing to do is to read design principles. Here is the link: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Answer (score 0):

With your `Person` prototype, you're explicitly defining as a 'Person' type object, where as with your `book`, it is just a generic object that happens to have a variable name of `book`.

`Object.getPrototypeOf(book)`

Console outputs `Object {}`

`Object.getPrototypeOf(person1)`

Console outputs `Person {}`

`Person` is not the same as `Object` and thus the check for equality returns false.